# SpriteKit Crash on SKCSprite::removeSubsprite in willMoveFromView:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

I am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash when trying to remove a subsprite. I realize there is an iOS 7.1 bug in `Sprite Kit` with removing a subsprite (almost exactly like this question: [Sprite Kit iOS 7.1 crash on removeFromParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399278/sprite-kit-ios-7-1-crash-on-removefromparent)), so I was trying to fix the issue be doing the following in my `SKScene`:

```
- (void)willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view {

    [self.leaderButton removeFromParent];
    self.leaderButton = nil;

    [self.twitter removeFromParent];
    self.twitter = nil;

    [self.facebook removeFromParent];
    self.facebook = nil;

}
```

For some reason my users are still getting a crash at the `[self.twitter removeFromParent]` line.

Why is this still happening? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you try it without setting the object to nil?

Comment: I am not actually able to reproduce the crash, I just am getting crash reports for it. So, remove the nil seems to be find for me...

Comment: Come again... i didn't understand "... to be find for me...". You mean fine as in that solved the problem?

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, it works fine for me. I am not actually able to replicate the crash that I am seeing from Crashlytics.

Comment: See my answer here, it might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597014/strange-exc-bad-access-spritekit-removesubsprite-crash