# SKCSprite::removeSubsprite(SKCSprite*) - EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x194d189a2) issue (exception thrown inconsistently) - only on iOS 7.1

Tags: sprite-kit, ios7.1

get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x194d189a2)

This is a result of selecting a SKSpriteNode on one SKScene, saving the selection to NSUserDefaults, then reading the NSUserDefaults in the new scene to init the new SKScene's experience - this can happen for any of the provided selections but is not an issue generated consistently. It smells of a framework bug that creates a memory leak, (though not verified in Instruments), not being plugged when SK's internal framework calls SKCSprite::removeSubsprite(SKCSprite*), which is not a direct call from myself.

At this point I've not done any formal [SKNode removeFromParent]; calls to remove my SKScene's SKSpriteNodes prior to transitioning to the new SKScene, although I have seen a few similar memory leak issues surrounding removeFromParent listed in stackoverflow.

Any thoughts? An obvious issue - does it merit a radar post or is this just a goof on my part? BTW never saw an issue with this before iOS 7.1,

Best,

Hungry Developer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sprite Kit iOS 7.1 crash on removeFromParent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399278/sprite-kit-ios-7-1-crash-on-removefromparent)