# Thread 1: EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1), address=0x6000000000000018)

Tags: sprite-kit, exc-bad-access, beta

Read all of the posts regarding this error being memory related and trying to access something that is no longer there.

**Problem:** Error pops up at virtually random intervals. It can appear after the first enemy is killed or the Nth enemy is killed. However, it ONLY appears when an enemy is killed.

**Testing:** Running iOS 8 beta 5, Xcode 6 beta 5 on iPhone 5s.

**Code flow:**

Enemy SKNodes class instances are created at start of level and stored in NSMutableArray for reference:

```
Goblin *newGoblin = [[Goblin alloc] initFacingDirection:1];
// set various properties…
[enemyGoblins addObject:newGoblin];
```

Player’s sword makes contact with enemy:

```
NSMutableArray *discardedItems = [NSMutableArray array];

for(Goblin *object in enemyGoblins)
{
    [object runBloodBurst:true damagePoints:_player.swordDamage];
    if(object.goblinHealth < 0)
        [discardedItems addObject:object];
}

if([discardedItems count] > 0)
    [enemyGoblins removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems];
```

In the Goblin class, the “die” code is:

```
if(self.goblinHealth < 0)
{
    SKAction *wait0 = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];

    SKAction *block0 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [self removeActionForKey:@"animation"];
        [self runAction:[_animations goblin_dieLeft]];
    }];

    SKAction *block1 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [self removeFromParent];
    }];

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[block0, wait0, block1]]];

}
```

**What I’ve tried:**
I disabled the “discardedItems” code because I thought ARC might dump the object from memory once the reference was lost and the subsequent Goblin class’ “die animation” would cause the crash but this did not resolve the issue. 
I tried zombies and breakpoints but got no useful clues either.

Am I barking up the wrong tree in regards to what I’ve tried or has anyone experienced a similar issue in Beta 5?

**EDIT**

Here is the backtrace:

> (lldb) bt
>   * thread #1: tid = 0x3264b, 0x000000018cb13434 SpriteKit`SKCSprite::update(double) + 404, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7000000000000018)
>       frame #0: 0x000000018cb13434 SpriteKit`SKCSprite::update(double) + 404
>       frame #1: 0x000000018cb13440 SpriteKit`SKCSprite::update(double) + 416
>       frame #2: 0x000000018cb13440 SpriteKit`SKCSprite::update(double) + 416
>       frame #3: 0x000000018cacbf28 SpriteKit`-[SKScene _update:] + 140
>       frame #4: 0x000000018cae63f8 SpriteKit`-[SKView(Private) _update:] + 568
>       frame #5: 0x000000018cae3a10 SpriteKit`-[SKView renderCallback:] + 764
>       frame #6: 0x000000018cae0a9c SpriteKit`__29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 60
>       frame #7: 0x000000018cb0d890 SpriteKit`-[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 272
>       frame #8: 0x000000010042ca9c libglInterpose.dylib`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 168
>       frame #9: 0x000000018c615b90 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 32
>       frame #10: 0x000000018c615a28 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 324
>       frame #11: 0x00000001897dddc0 IOKit`IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 376
>       frame #12: 0x00000001885dcf34 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 180
>       frame #13: 0x00000001885f1b38 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
>       frame #14: 0x00000001885f1a98 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
>       frame #15: 0x00000001885efa18 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1640
>       frame #16: 0x000000018851d664 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
>       frame #17: 0x000000019154f5a4 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
>       frame #18: 0x000000018ccd6164 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
>     * frame #19: 0x0000000100165530 CarcerQuest`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdab9d8) + 116 at main.m:16
>       frame #20: 0x000000019885aa08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
>   (lldb)

Comment: [Understanding EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://loufranco.com/blog/understanding-exc_bad_access)

Comment: post the call stack and exact line where error occurs, add exception breakpoint to find out

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - added backtrace

Comment: @CodeMonkey - Each enemy class has a 'dead BOOL' which prevents anything else running once health is less than 0. The issue what has me scratching my head is the crash is almost random. Sometimes it happens on the 3rd enemy and sometimes on the 20th. I have added several "If(object != nil)" into my code but the crash still occurs.

Comment: What line does it crash on ?

Comment: @prototypical - I do not know. It is not displaying a line.

Comment: Use NSLog lines to try and pinpoint where it happens, that's what I'd do first.

Comment: @prototypical - That was the first thing I did. The crashes never seem to stay in one part of the code.

Comment: well, on a given crash, you are going to know what was the last NSLog, and that's a hint for us all. We don't know, so hard to help if you are holding back on hints for us, right ?

Comment: also... this is iOS and Xcode Beta. So, that opens a whole other can of worms.

Comment: @prototypical - You are right about beta being a can of worms. I do believe this is where the issue is. I appreciate your input on this.

Comment: @sangony Maybe this question can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399278/sprite-kit-ios-7-1-crash-on-removefromparent - it's not ios 8 , but has a similar SKCSprite in backtrace and is a removal issue. My guess is that something is trying to use the removed node. Do you have anything that stores a reference to these nodes ?

Comment: @sangony I think the last comment on the linked question is an example of what I suggested in my last comment. Something of that nature might be going on. Also, turning off the showPhysics property would also be worth trying, if you have it enabled.

Comment: @prototypical - Very interesting. It does sound very similar to what I have right now. I will try out some of the proposed solutions and see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: @prototypical - No joy. I ended up removing EVERY instance of code which could lead to an object losing a reference and I still get the same kind of errors. This is definitely a beta bug.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing the code, I'd like to take a look at it. Someone in that question was mentioning showsPhysics using SKShapeNode for the bounding boxes. Do you get this error with showsPhysics disabled ?

Comment: @prototypical - so I think I finally isolated the pesky bug. Let me know if you are available for a chat...

Comment: my email is on my profile. Definitely interested in what the issue was.

Comment: @prototypical - Thanks for responding. I posted the issue in my most recent question. It had to do with the calling a method containing blocks before completion. I do not know if this is an iOS 8 issue or something else. I found a workaround but still do not understand the root cause of it.

Comment: I used your code in a iOS7/XCode 5 project and I didn't get any crashes while repeatedly calling bloodBurst quickly, however I don't know what your `SKAction` definition is, so I just made a simple definition. That potentially could be the issue or not, but without seeing the `SKAction` definition can't rule it out.

Comment: If you want to github the project, I'd take a look at it. It's hard to know if there aren't other potential causes without seeing the full picture.

Comment: I tried it in my iOS8/Xcode6 beta with your code from the other question, and the only thing different would be the `SKAction` definition for that animation. I used just a typical `animateTextures` acton with a 60 frame animation. No crashes and no need for an ivar.

Answer (score 3):

change

`[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[block0, wait0, block1]]];`

to

`[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[block0, wait0]] completion:^{
        [_self removeFromParent];
    }];`

I ran in to the same issue when updating IOS7 code to run on IOS8, and using the completion block fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the comments of your question, I'm not sure if you've solved this problem, and your code snippet isn't complete enough for me to see your issue, but I recently ran into a similar problem and it took me a while to figure out, so I'd post it in case it's helpful to you or some future reader of the post.

You can see my code change here: https://github.com/ik/2048/commit/3ffec547367320c7e179624a14ac5867ed1acea2

Basically what happens is `runAction` is async. It is executed in the next screen refresh cycle (hence the display link call in your stack trace). So if you call `removeSomething` after your `runAction`, it can be executed before the action is run, and you will crash.

At least that's what caught me - I don't know why it never occurred in iOS 7. See code below.

```
- [self removeFromParentCell]; // Used to call it here - wrong.
  SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:GSTATE.animationDuration];
  SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
- [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, remove]]];
+ [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, remove]] completion:^{
+   [self removeFromParentCell];  // This is right.
+ }];
```

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the Apple Support Forums and running the same project on iOS 7, it appears this is a Beta release bug and not faulty code after all.